# How to dynamically change style mode in vueJS

Tags: javascript, css, typescript, vue.js, sass

i want to create features where we can change style on click button.

in my case im using sass/scss for my styling..

for example i have 3 different style, default.scss, dark.scss and system.scss..
the code is like this for dark.scss

```
// Mode
$mode: dark;

// Initialize
@import "init";

// Components
@import "./core/components/components";
@import "components/components";

// Layout
@import "layout/layout";
@import "./core/layout/docs/layout";
```

and on the app.vue

```
<style lang="scss">
@import "assets/sass/dark";
</style>
```

and on my test.vue i create button to change the style

```
<v-btn @click="light" />
<v-btn @click="dark" />
```

is that possible to change style with button click?

how i can do it, for example to change `@import "assets/sass/dark";` to `@import "assets/sass/light";` from file `app.vue`?

Comment: If you're using webpack you could use `require` in a condition.

Answer (score 1):

You can conditionnally import with sass

```
<style lang="scss">
.dark-mode {
    @import "assets/sass/dark";
}
.light-mode {
    @import "assets/sass/light";
}
</style>
```

Bind the class of your App main `div`

```
<div :class="selectedMode">
    
</div>
```

There is a lot of way to handle `selectedMode` but I think you should already know how to do it

Comment: the problem is on that file scss, there's another file scss that i import..
in my case i only need to change `$mode: dark/light`..

Comment: because i cant do it on frontend side, so i create 2 different file base scss..

Comment: not sure to understand but ... ok

Answer (score 0):

i solve this issue with this..

1. store mode to `localstorage` and reload page

> ```
> const changeMode = (mode) => {
>   localStorage.setItem("mode", mode);
>   window.location.reload();
> };
> ```

2. check the `localstorage` and load style

> ```
> if (localStorage.getItem("mode") && localStorage.getItem("mode") == "dark") {
>   require("@/assets/sass/plugins.dark.scss");
>   require("@/assets/sass/style.dark.scss");
> } else {
>   require("@/assets/sass/plugins.scss");
>   require("@/assets/sass/style.scss");
> }
> ```